# Using SupportMapFragment with XML attributes in FragmentContainerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-xml, google-maps-android-api-3

In my app I used a `FragmentContainerView` to keep a single fragment, extended from `SupportMapFragment`.
Just like this:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:name="com.package.name.fragments.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Reading the docs about SupportMapFragment I found out, that it is possible to set up its initial state using xml attributes ([Like here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map#using_xml_attributes), or even more important, [like here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/cloud-based-map-styling#add-map-id)). However, adding these attributes to `FragmentContainerView` does not affect map.
So, the following code doesn't work as expected:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:name="com.package.name.fragments.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    map:cameraTargetLat="11"
    map:cameraTargetLng="10"
    map:cameraZoom="10.0"
    map:mapType="normal"
    map:mapId="@string/google_maps_style"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The style is not set, nor does the latitude, longitude or zoom.
The only workaround I found is:

```
<fragment
    class="com.package.name.fragments.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    map:cameraTargetLat="11"
    map:cameraTargetLng="10"
    map:cameraZoom="10.0"
    map:mapType="normal"
    map:mapId="@string/google_maps_style"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

This one works as expected, but as far as I know `FragmentContainerView` was made to replace `fragment` tag. So the question is, is it possible to pass XML attributes to the fragment, contained in `FragmentContainerView`?

EDIT:
Thanks to @ianhanniballake I found out that in both cases attributes are passed to the `onInflate()` method of the fragment correctly. But it doesn't solve the main problem, why the parameters specified by these attributes (such as camera latitude, longitude or zoom) are finally set if the fragment was defined in `fragment` tag and are not - if in `FragmentContainerView` tag?
Long story short, why isn't map in `FragmentContainerView` initialized with XML attributes correctly?

Comment: Both of them call `onInflate()` on the Fragment and pass the values through. Does that method get called for your `MapFragment` class?

Comment: @ianhanniballake It does, and I also checked which attributes are passed to it in `AttributeSet` parameter: in both cases all specified attributes are passed correctly.

Comment: So it doesn't sound like a problem with `FragmentContainerView` at all then?

Comment: @ianhanniballake no, its not about any problem. It's about possibility. Is it possible to make it work as expected with `FragmentContainerView `? And if yes, what to do for it?

Comment: Well if the attributes are being passed to the `SupportMapFragment`, I'm confused what your problem is? It seems like it *is* working according to what you are saying?

Comment: @ianhanniballake, the attributes are passed, but the map is not modified the way it is expected. For example, `cameraZoom` is passed in `onInflate()` method, but the zoom does not change, it remains default. Unlike in case with `fragment` tag. My question is why.